# What does customize: Set for Current Session do?

Tags: customize, variables

I have a variable that I want to switch between two different values and have it apply for the whole session. I'm able to do this using `M-x customize-variable` and picking "Set for Current Session".

What functions is this calling? I'd love to be able to set a variable for the current session (NOT just for the current buffer, and NOT for future sessions) without using `customize`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any change to the variable is equivalent here, so just `M-x set-variable` or `(setq THE-VAR A-NEW-VALUE)` is sufficient.

The function called when you click `Set for Current Session` is `custom-variable-set`. (Well, actually it is more complicated - it boils down to calling either the value of `(get SYMBOL 'custom-set)`, where `SYMBOL` is the option symbol or function `set-default`.)

The advantage of using `Set for Current Session` in the Customize UI is that you can use the Customize UI to edit the value - e.g., menus, completion, etc.

With the Customize UI there are thus two steps to changing a variable value:

1. Edit the value.
2. Set for session.

If you do not set the value (set for session) and you only edit it, then the variable value is not changed at all.

---

UPDATE, per comments:

In Customize, when editing the custom group, you can call function `custom-group-set` on the widget for the group. In terms of existing keyboard key bindings, you can use `TAB` to move to the `State` button, then `RET` to "push" the button.

Then you are shown a plain-text menu, with indications of number keys you can hit to choose one of the menu items. In this case, you hit `0` to choose the `Set for Current Session` action. IOW, you can use keyboard keybindings to set the edited changes for a group in Customize.

Other key bindings in Customize:

- `C-c C-c` for `Custom-set/[Set for Current Session]`
- `C-x C-s` for `Custom-save/[Save for Future Sessions]`

Comment: I don't think so. I'm customizing c-basic-offset, and `M-x set-variable` only applies to the current buffer. It even says in the prompt "Set c-basic offset buffer-locally to value:".

Comment: As always, you can use `setq-default` to change the default value of a buffer-local variable.

Comment: Yes! This is the answer I needed. I can do `M-: (setq-default c-basic-offset 4)`. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of clicking `Set for Current Session`, what I execute with `M-x` to do the same thing (apply currently changed to session), or keybind?

Comment: @Andy: `M-x set-variable` or `M-x customize-set-variable` sets the value for the session. But see the answer.

Comment: @Drew I don't think either of those are what I'm looking for, as they both query for a variable to change when called. Instead, I have the `customize-group` menu open, and have changed items for the menu, and I want a keybinding to apply to the session the changes made in the menu (akin to clicking `Set for Current Session`).

Comment: @Andy: You can call function `custom-group-set` on the widget for the custom group. You are apparently using Customize to edit group state but you don't want to use it to set the changes. In terms of existing keyboard key bindings, you can use `TAB` to move to the `State` button, the `RET` to "push" the button. Then you are shown a plain-text menu, with indications of number keys you can hit to choose one of the menu items. In this case, you hit `0` to choose the `Set for Current Session` action. IOW, you can already use keyboard keybindings to set the edited changes for a group in Customize.

Comment: @Drew Thank you, that was part of what I was looking for, the last part was: `C-c C-c` for `Custom-set`/`[Set for Current Session]` (and `C-x C-s` for `Custom-save`/`[Save for Future Sessions]`) per [Changing a Variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Changing-a-Variable.html).

Comment: @Andy: Thx. I've incorporated that info into the answer (comments can be deleted at any time).

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use `customize-set-variable`, i.e.

```
(customize-set-variable 'some-variable "some value")
```

Variables set this way (after your custom file has been loaded) will be considered as unsaved customizations, just like variables `Set for Current Session`. You can list unsaved customizations using `customize-unsaved`.