# How to change a variable value in the current buffer?

Tags: customize, variables, local-variables

I spent a long time looking for this and kept getting reference to `M-x customize`. But, that didn't give me access to certain variables like `comment-start`. I couldn't access `comment-start` with `M-x customize-option` either.

I decided to look for a way to use `setq` in the current buffer, but couldn't find that so I figured I'd document it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M-: (setq comment-start "/**")`.

Documented in the [emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Eval.html).

Found via [this comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/what-does-customize-set-for-current-session-do#comment6713_4269).

Comment: FYI: You can accept your own answer to your question. It's good to have accepted answers - helps others who have the same question.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I still have some time until it will let me do so. It also gives a chance for others to post a better or alternative solution.